# How to check number of columns in CSV with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have two buttons - 'Input the File' which uploads a CSV file from PC and 'Load File' which loads it for other utility in my application.

```
<input type="file" class="custom-file-input form-control-sm" id="inputFile" onchange="handleFiles(this.files)" accept=".csv">
<label class="custom-file-label col-form-label-sm" for="inputFile" onclick="checkFunc()">Input the File</label>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark rounded w1-right set-sql" id="lfb">Load File</button>
```

I want to add a js function to the Load File button so that when it loads file which is uploaded from the local PC, it checks the number of columns the file has and whether it is X number of columns. And then displays a success message(if X columns) or failure message(if more than or less than X number of columns).

Here is what I have tried. The function is not working. What can I do/change here?

```
async function checkFunc() {
    
        if (inputFile.files.length) {
          try {
            var csvFileInText = await inputFile.files[0].text();
            console.log(csvFileInText);
                           
            var arrObje = [];
            var lines = csvFileInText.split('\n');
            var lineA = lines[0].split(',');

            let linesize = lineA.length;

            if (linesize == 3){
              alert("File uploaded successfully.");
            }
            else{
              alert("File was not uploaded. Please check the instructions.");
            }       

          } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
          }
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to split on the below characters that is why it isn't working for you:

```
let lines = csvFileInText.split(/\r?\n/);
```